# how to config sanctum laravel

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

I try to access by wrong token in sanctum laravel but it return
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST instead of message: unauthorized. how can I solve this ?

This is my api route:
[image]

This is my controller:
[image]

and this is my result:
[image]

Comment: What is your requested route? Inside routes doesn't exists it...

Comment: sorry I did not understand your question. Can you explain more clearly?

Comment: I didn't see route for resend() method

Comment: I wrote it in the bottom of api route.

Comment: Edit and send real code; remove code pictures.

Comment: Share your code not the image.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you talk about token, maybe you meant `JWT`, which is for REST and/or JSON Web-API, and normally does not allow "get" as access-method.

Your error-message simply means that the way you try to make the request is not allowed.

Hence, either allow it by replacing:

```
Route::get('my-url')-> ...
```

With:

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'my-url')-> ...
```

Or change your request to make a Post request instead of a Get request.

> Example how to change?!
> If you did send us an example how you make a request, we could provide you how to do it right.